# How to extract only numbers from string except substring with special character in beginning of numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, data-extraction

my plan is extract numbers from string except numbers with special character. What I mean? 
Please imagine a following (like Excel formula):

```
=$A12+A$345+A6789
```

I need to extract numbers where in beginning of them doesn't exist any character $, so result of right regex should be:

```
12
6789
```

I made some investigation where I used a following regex:

```
/[A-Z][0-9]+(?![/W])/g
```

which extracts:

```
A12
A6789
```

I was thinking to use nested regex (to extract numbers from that result additionally) but I have no idea if it possible. My source code in javascript so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/janzitniak/fvczu7a0/7/

Regards

Jan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const regex = /(?<ref>\$?[A-Z]+(?<!\$)[0-9]+)/g;
const str = `=$A12+A$345+A6789`;

const refs = [...(str.matchAll(regex) || [])].map(result => result.groups.ref);

console.log(refs)
```

Matches any string containing A-Z once or more that is preceded by a $ zero or one times, followed by 0-9 once or more but not preceded by a $, all followed by + zero or one times.

You ignore all matched groups, but capture the one you want, referenced as `ref` (you can call it whatever you want).

Output:

```
["$A12","A6789"]
```

If you want just the number part, you can use:

```
const regex = /\$?[A-Z]+(?<!\$)(?<num>[0-9]+)/g;
const str = `=$A12+A$345+A6789`;
const nums = [...(str.matchAll(regex) || [])].map(result => +result.groups.num);
console.log(nums)
```

Output:

```
[12, 6789]
```

Comment: By your approach I learned about Named groups; I wasn't aware of that and was still counting group capturing parentheses within my reg-expressions. Thanks, and upvote.

Comment: @ibraheem can you help me once again please? How can I increment ref output if I want to have the following result  ["$A13","A6790"]?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const charSequence = '=$A12+A$345+A6789';

const numberList = (charSequence
  .split(/\$\d+/)       // - split at "'$' followed by one or more numbers".
  .join('')             // - join array of split results into string again.
  .match(/\d+/g) || []) // - match any number-sequence or fall back to empty array.
  .map(str => +str);    // - typecast string into number.
//.map(str => parseInt(str, 10)); // parse string into integer.

console.log('numberList : ', numberList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

> @ibraheem can you help me once again please? How can I increment ref output if I want to have the following result ["$A13","A6790"]? - JanZitniak 23 mins ago

... the `split/join/match` approach can be iterated very fast, thus it proves to be quite flexible.

```js
const charSequence = '=$A13+A$345+A6790';

const numberList = (charSequence
  .split(/\$\d+/)       // - split at "'$' followed by one or more numbers".
  .join('')             // - join array of split results into string again.
  .match(/\$*[A-Z]\d+/g) || []);  // - match any sequence of an optional '$' followed
                                  //   by 1 basic latin uppercase character followed
                                  //   by one or more number character(s).

console.log('numberList : ', numberList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

> Peter thank you for your quick response about increment but on start I have const charSequence = '=$A12+A$345+A6789'; and as output I need ["$A13","A6790"]. – JanZitniak

... ok, finally one is going to get a full picture of the entire problem ... which is (1) getting rid of the not necessary patterns ...(2) matching numbers within specific patterns *AND somehow remember the latter* (3) increment such numbers *AND somehow rework them into their remembered/recallable pattern*.

```js
const anchorSequence = '=$A12+A$345+A6789';

const listOfIncrementedAnchorCoordinates = [...(anchorSequence

  // - split at "'$' followed by one or more numbers".
  .split(/\$\d+/)

  // - join array of split results into string again.
  .join('')

  // - match any sequence of an optional '$' followed by 1 basic latin 
  //   uppercase character followed by one or more number character(s)
  //   and store each capture into a named group.
  .matchAll(/(?<anchor>\$*[A-Z])(?<integer>\d+)/g) || [])

  // map each regexp result from a list of RegExpStringIterator entries.
].map(({ groups }) => `${ groups.anchor }${ (+groups.integer + 1) }`);

console.log('listOfIncrementedAnchorCoordinates : ', listOfIncrementedAnchorCoordinates);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

> Peter if you are interest(...ed) in another problem I have one. How can I change const anchorSequence = '=$A12+A$345+A6789'; to following output ["B$345","B6789"]? I mean to change letter to next one in alphabetical order (if it is A then change to B, if it is B change to C and so on) if letter doesn't start with $. In my example it should change only A$345 and A6789. – JanZitniak

... with a little thinking effort it was not that hard to iterate/refactor the version before to this last one ...

```js
const anchorSequence = '=$A12+A$345+A6789';

const listOfIncrementedColumns = [...(anchorSequence

  // - split at "'$' followed by 1 basic latin uppercase character 
  //   followed by one or more number character(s)".
  .split(/\$[A-Z]\d+/)

  // - join array of split results into string again.
  .join('')

  // - match any sequence of 1 basic latin uppercase character
  //   followed by an optional '$' followed by one or more number
  //   character(s) and store each capture into a named group.
  .matchAll(/(?<column>[A-Z])(?<anchor>\$*)(?<row>\d+)/g) || [])

  // map each regexp result from a list of RegExpStringIterator entries.
].map(({ groups }) => [

  // - be aware that "Z" (charCode:90) will be followed by "[" (charCode:91)
  // - thus, the handling of this edge case still needs to be implemented.
  String.fromCharCode(groups.column.charCodeAt(0) + 1),
  groups.anchor,
  groups.row

].join(''));

console.log('listOfIncrementedColumns : ', listOfIncrementedColumns);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @JanZitniak ... here we go ... the `split/join/match` approach can be iterated very fast.

Comment: Peter thank you for your quick response about increment but on start I have const charSequence = '=$A12+A$345+A6789'; and as output I need ["$A13","A6790"].

Comment: Ok, finally one is gong to get a full picture of the entire problem ... which is (1) getting rid of the not necessary patterns ...(2) matching numbers within specific patterns *AND somehow remember the latter* (3) increment such numbers *AND somehow rework them into their remembered/recallable pattern*

Comment: Peter Seliger I would like to tell you big thank you for your willingness to solve my whole problem! It works as I expected.

Comment: Peter if you are interesting in another problem I have one. How can I change const anchorSequence = '=$A12+A$345+A6789'; to following output ["B$345","B6789"]? I mean to change letter to next one in alphabetical order (if it is A then change to B, if it is B change to C and so on) if letter doesn't start with $. In my example it should change only A$345 and A6789.

Comment: Peter thank you for your all effort, you helped me a lot!

Comment: Dear Peter, if I can ask you again I would like to replace, in effective way, an anchorSequence to anchorSequence which meets my goal, e.g. const anchorSequence = '=$A12+A$345+A6789' to const anchorSequence = '=$A12+B$345+B6789' in my last question respectively from const charSequence = '=$A12+A$345+A6789' to anchorSequence = '=$A13+A$345+A6790' in my before last one.

Comment: My single answer does already provide at least 3 different solutions based on one approach. Each solution targets a different use case. But within all those solutions every single technique already has been provided in order to help you solve what you are asking for right now. Please, at least come up with an own idea/approach/code, and then, only in case you don't succeed, feel free to ask again ... just edit your original question and provide your own part towards a solution to it.